# Why does laravel 11 force me to configure a database to execute a new project?

Tags: php, laravel

I recently installed Laravel 11 to test some of the framework's features. After the initial installation, I was asked a series of questions that previously did not appear in previous versions, such as:

> What type of unit tests should be installed (PEST or PHPUnit)?
>
> What type of database will be used (Mysql, SQLite...)?

In addition to a series of other questions, which did not appear in previous versions of Laravel.

After completion, I ran a `php artisan serve`, and to my surprise Laravel complained about the non-existence of a table called sessions:

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = 33u9rgf824u5n84n84yng8ytngtng limit 1 laravel error
```

To solve this problem, I need to configure my new Database in MySQL, declare it in `.env` file and run a migration.

At this point, laravel installed 9 new tables, which are: `cache`, `cache_locks`, `failed_jobs`, `jobs`, `job_batches`, `migrations`, `password_reset_tokens`, `sessions` and `users`.

Does this mean that every Laravel project I start, I am required to have a database to install these tables?

And is there a possibility of creating a project in Laravel 11 without the need for this?

Comment: Laravel 11 seems to have the database as the default session driver ([here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/11.x/config/session.php#L21)) you can change that to `file` (which was the previous default behavior).

Comment: Most of the time you can change what base "driver" you want to use in configuration files, so if this happens to you again, related to other features, first check the documentation and then the related config file and set the desired driver